# CircleCIでworkflowを定義しなくてもjobが動いたのはどうしてですか？

Tags: circleci

CircleCIで[Pythonのチュートリアル](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-python/)を実行していました。
設定ファイルを見ると、workflowで定義したジョブを実行するように見えます。にも関わらず、チュートリアルの通りに進めたらworkflowのない `config.yaml`がCircleCI上で実行されてしまいました。

どうしてか、理由がわかる方がいらっしゃいましたら教えてください。

ファイルは以下になります。

```
version: 2
jobs:
build:
    working_directory: ~/circleci-demo-python-django
    docker:
    - image: circleci/python:3.6.4
        environment:
        PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT: true
        DATABASE_URL: postgresql://root@localhost/circle_test?sslmode=disable
    - image: circleci/postgres:9.6.2
        environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: root
        POSTGRES_DB: circle_test
    steps:
    - checkout
    - run: sudo chown -R circleci:circleci /usr/local/bin
    - run: sudo chown -R circleci:circleci /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
    - restore_cache:
        key: deps9-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "Pipfile.lock" }}
    - run:
        command: |
            sudo pip install pipenv
            pipenv install
    - save_cache:
        key: deps9-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "Pipfile.lock" }}
        paths:
            - ".venv"
            - "/usr/local/bin"
            - "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages"
    - run:
        command: |
            pipenv run "python manage.py test"
    - store_test_results:
        path: test-results
    - store_artifacts:
        path: test-results
        destination: tr1
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

Workflowの利用は必須ではありません。必要に応じて、Workflowなしでジョブを実行することが可能です。
[Using Workflows to Schedule Jobs - CircleCI](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/workflows/)

## 解説

Workflow機能を利用すると、ジョブの実行順や依存関係を指定することが可能です。一方、 `build` という名前のジョブを作成してあげることで、Workflowなしでの実行が可能です。

> If you are using Workflows, jobs must have a name that is unique within the .circleci/config.yml file.
>
> If you are **not** using workflows, the jobs map must contain a job named `build`. This build job is the default entry-point for a run that is triggered by a push to your VCS provider. It is possible to then specify additional jobs and run them using the CircleCI API.
>
> Note: Jobs have a maximum runtime of 5 hours. If your jobs are timing out, consider running some of them in parallel.
> [Configuring CircleCI - CircleCI](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#jobs)